# Boolean Difference function adding new face unexpectedly

Tags: modifiers

[image: Image showing extra face added.]In Blender 2.91.0 I am trying to make a cube recess in another cube by using the 'boolean - Difference' function.

For some reason blender doesn't take the second cube away cleanly from the first cube. It adds a new face to the front of the remaining cube (see attached pic).

I use 'snap to' vertex to ensure the vertices are all aligned- but same problem occurred.
I made the cube used to apply the difference a little larger to ensure it was outside the flat plane of the first cube, but same problem.
I tried using new cubes, but problem still remains.
I then tried a second cube bigger than the entire face of the first cube and applied 'difference' again, but the extra edge remained.

I want to apply texture to the front surface but the extra face will make alignment difficult. Besides as far as I can see this shouldn't happen.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a face within a face without edges that connect this inner face to the outer face, thus the edges you're showing, otherwise the outer face will overlap the inner face, meaning the inner face couldn't exist, or it could exist but it wouldn't be part of the same mesh. As for your texture question, I don't see in what way it will cause any issue, just select the front faces and unwrap.

[image]

Comment: Yes okay that makes sense. I was using the 'difference' function and this connect wasn't there but I realised it was because the face was reaching the outside already.  As for the texture problem. Maybe its the way the building is built but half of the texture map is not used because the uv map has put the inner faces as well. Thanks for the help